# Is there a way to get an email from Twitter if and only if someone tweets at me?

Tags: twitter

I see that there's a setting on Twitter's "Settings" page that allows me to receive emails from Twitter "When you have new notifications". The problem is that most of my notifications are for accounts that are spam-following me.

Is there any way to receive an email from Twitter if, but only if, someone tweets at me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like Twitter can do this natively, but this is easy to do with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com).

Trigger: [Twitter channel](https://ifttt.com/twitter), New mention of you

Action: [Email channel](https://ifttt.com/email), Send me an email

You might set up the subject and body like this:

subject: `You were mentioned by @{{UserName}} on Twitter!`

body:
`@{{UserName}}: {{Text}}<br>
<br>
via Twitter {{LinkToTweet}}`

There are several pre-built applets you can just use, such as [this one](https://ifttt.com/applets/TKTaSNn4-twitter-mention).