# How do I disable the "interesting tweet" notification type on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, notifications, spam-prevention

In the past, I would get Twitter notifications when someone liked or retweeted a tweet, or started following me.  If I hadn't visited Twitter for a while after, I'd get an e-mail saying there were notifications available.

For the past month or so, I've been regularly getting nonspecific e-mails like "See the 2 notifications ready and waiting just for you! [Take a look](https://twitter.com/i/notifications)." Clicking the link shows that the "notifications" are just specific Tweets that Twitter wanted to direct my attention to for whatever reason (e.g. some of the people I follow liked/replied to it).  These notification types are shown with a blue Twitter icon, different than the heart icon used for "XYZ liked this tweet," the generic person icon used for "ABC followed you," the picture icon used for a reply, etc.

**I'd like to disable this entire class of notifications:** all of the ones that would use the blue Twitter logo icon.  It's a transparent bid for increasing traffic and time-on-site but focuses attention on low-quality content I'm not interested in, and ignoring all notifications means reducing the social interaction part of the network that I might not want to get rid of.

I'm using only the Web version, with no mobile app.

Under e-mail notifications, my options are set to explicitly DISABLE "activity from your network" including "Top Tweets and Stories:"
[image: Activity from network is DISABLED]

The "Learn More" link next to "You have new notifications" goes [here](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/updating-email-preferences#tweet-activity), which says in part:

> You can receive notifications when your Tweets or Retweets are Retweeted or liked, when you are mentioned in a Tweet, if you are followed by someone new, or when someone from your contacts joins Twitter. These are collected on your Notifications page.
>
> As of June 2017, Twitter now sends a digest email referencing all your unread notifications about activity related to your account, instead of separate emails for each type and instance. This is to reduce the noise of Twitter email in your inbox.

There's no mention in there about the "Twitter" type notifications generated when Twitter just wants to direct attention to certain tweets or increase traffic, nor anything about how to disable that.

Twitter's [page about the Notifications timeline](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/understanding-the-notifications-timeline) similarly says nothing about the new annoying class of "you might be interested in this" notifications:

> The Notifications timeline offers a simple way to see how others on Twitter are interacting with you.
> From the Notifications timeline, you’ll be able to see which of your Tweets have been liked, plus the latest Retweets (of your Tweets), Tweets directed to you (replies and mentions) and your new followers.
> You can view your notifications in two ways: All shows you notifications for account activity like new followers, Retweets, mentions, and likes. Mentions shows you notifications only for Tweets that mention your username.

The [Web notifications settings page](https://twitter.com/settings/web_notifications) shows that I have Web notifications turned off, but that "These settings do not change your notifications timeline. [Learn more.](https://help.twitter.com/en/managing-your-account/enabling-web-and-browser-notifications)"  The Learn more page similarly makes no mention of this new annoying class of notifications, only that

> You can get notifications for things like Direct Messages, follows, likes, replies to your Tweets, mentions, and Retweets of your Tweets.

**How do I disable this new class of Twitter notifications specifically??**

Comment: Same question here. I started getting these emails a few weeks ago and I'm not interested in them. I'm annoyed enough by "recommendations" when I'm _using_ Twitter... I don't want any such thing when I'm not actively using Twitter.

Comment: This answer may be useful: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/114180/21262

Answer (score 1):

There's a link to opt-out from these emails in the email itself, click that will disable you from getting those type of emails (it'll be at the bottom of the email). It will not disable all emails because Twitter will still want you to see your Direct Messages and other more important notifications. Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score -1):

turn off your notifications in your settings

Comment: Where in settings do you see the option to disable this specific type of notification?